# How to wait in Unity c# function?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I have to make a code where the cube disappears in a couple of seconds after the player touches it. But I have no idea how to make it because `StartCoroutine(name());` works only in `IEnumerator name(){}` like this:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(waiter());
}

IEnumerator waiter()
{    
    //Wait for 4 seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);  
}
```

but I need to wait in `private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {}` function.
I can't do something like this:

```
void start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Text());
    }

    IEnumerator Text() 
    {
        private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
            StartCoroutine(Text());
            rd = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            rd.enabled = false;
        }
        

    }
```

How to make a cooldown in `OnCollisionEnter` function?

Comment: the trivial way to do things like this in Unity is simply the **Invoke** command.  It couldn't be easier.

Comment: @Fattie to me `Invoke` has its good side and also a bad one: It is not cancelable. The Coroutine can still be stopped if e.g. the component is disabled in the meantime (let's e.g. say you open a Pause menu). The `Invoke` will be invoked after the time passed no matter what ;)

Comment: You know, there is actually a cancel-invoke believe or not!  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html  My point is just that for beginners, for trivial timers like this, you can just use "Invoke" - which is I'd say the very reason Unity tossed it in, make it easy for hobbyists ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Start() { }

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    StartCoroutine(Text());
}

IEnumerator Text() 
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    rd = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rd.enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nested methods make no sense.

Why not simply make [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) a Coroutine itself:

```
// Best you already reference this via the Inspector in Unity
[SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;

private void Awake ()
{
    // Alternatively get it ONCE on runtime
    if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

private IEnumerator OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
   
    _renderer.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `OnCollisionEnter` auto-wired by Unity though? I thought it required a specific signature as it's called by rigid body in response to collision events - does it automatically get executed as a coroutine if you build the method signature to look like one (might be useful info for someone else)?

Comment: Yes, but if you make it IEnumerator it is automatically started as a Coroutine by Unity ;) Works with most event based messages except some exceptions like e.g. `Awake`, `Update`, `OnDestroy` .. but works with e.g. `Start`, `OnTriggerEnter`, `OnCollisionEnter`, `OnTriggerExit`, `OnCollisionExit, ...

Comment: That's useful info to know, I didn't find that in the docs

Comment: @Charleh yep it's pretty hidden ^^ see e.g. at the bottom of [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) -> `OnCollisionEnter can be a co-routine, simply use the yield statement in the function.` .. a bit confusing tbh it would be way better to understand if they would simply say `...simply let it return IEnumerator` because that is what is ment actually ;)